# Emailing comments on a case

Tags: administration, case, configuration

We use cases extensively throughout the organisation. I want to be able to have the option of sending a comment by email when I add a comment to a case. Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use workflow rules under Create | Workflow & Approvals | Workflow Rules then Create New Rule, choose Case Comment as the object, and trigger on object being created if you want it to happen on each new comment.